# Failed Testing Switch React Native with Testing Library

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-hooks, react-testing-library

I'm getting the following error when trying to simulate an event using fireEvent  "onChange" : "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"

My component :

```
const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState<boolean>(policy_value);

  const handleChangeSwitch = () => { 
    const value = !isActive;
    settingsService.updatePolicy(id, value);
    setIsActive(!isActive);
  };

    <Switch value={isActive}  onChange={handleChangeSwitch} testID="policy-switch"/>
```

My test:

```
const { getByTestId } = render(<Policy data={mockPolicy} />);

let switchButton = getByTestId("policy-switch")

fireEvent(switchButton, "onChange", { value: true });

expect(settingsService.updatePolicy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

I tried:

```
fireEvent(switchButton, "onChange", { value: true });
fireEvent(switchButton, "onChange", true);
fireEvent(switchButton, "onChange");
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your onChange handler?

Comment: added onChange handler, but the error remains without it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem by changing `onChange` to `onValueChange`

```
<Switch value={isActive}  onValueChange={handleChangeSwitch} testID="policy-switch"/>


const { getByTestId } = render(<Policy data={mockPolicy} />);

let switchButton = getByTestId("policy-switch")

fireEvent(switchButton, "onValueChange", true);

expect(settingsService.updatePolicy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```